# How do I pass a member of a function in another function

Tags: c++

I have two methods which are `getData(float weight, float hieght)` and `calBMI()`.

Now in `getData` I am getting weight and height from a user.

I want to know how do I pass that weight and height I got from `getData` to `calBMI` method?

Comment: `calBMI(float weight, float hieght)`? If you can't change the signatures then there are other questions: Are those member functions or free? Can you use member variables/global variables? There isn't really enough information to answer your question.

Comment: Maybe you have a person class and that has a weight, height member variables that you assign with the values from getData(float weight, float height) and then with the instance of the person class you can call calBMI() with that signature. So you can do Person person_one(weight, height); person_one.calBMI();

Comment: maybe `setWeightHeight` would be a more descriptive name if you are letting the user set the values in your class instance.

Comment: I think it's better to show us your functions here